# How to new an Object according to interface in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface like this:

```
interface Response {
    items: {
        productId: string;
        productName: string;
        price: number;
    }[]
}

interface APIResponse {
    items: {
        productId: string;
        productName: string;
        price: number;
        factoryId: string,
        status: number,
        category: number,
        priority: number
    }[]
}
```

now I have a function return `Response`:

```
async function list(): promise<Response> {
    // data.htw.cart.list return APIResponse
    const rv = await data.htw.cart.list(postJson)
    return rv
}
```

However, `data.htw.cart.list` return `APIResponse`, I just need `Response`, I get too much data.

every time I need to do this:

```
return {
  items: rv.items.map(item => {
    return {
      productId: item.productId,
      productName: item.productName,
      price: item.price
    }
  })
}
```

**I want to have a tool to remove some data in `APIResponse` which make `APIResponse` becomes `Response`?**

Two things to point out:

1. `APIResponse` always include `Response`
2. key name in `Response` which includes is the same as in `APIResponse`

Comment: You can have `APIResponse` extend `Response`...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I sorry, `TypeScript` just do not give me an error in fact, I just want to remove some data when I return

Comment: Indeed, you code compiles fine.

Comment: I don't think this is a Typescript issue.  You're reporting that your function `data.htw.cart.list` returns data formatted as your interface `APIResponse`.  If your function returns that datatype, then you need to modify the `data.htw.cart.list` function itself, not the `list()` function.  Your proposed solution, mapping the response to a more minimal subset of data, seems optimal to me.

Comment: @EricDauenhauer yes, it is not typescript issue, I just need a tool to remove some data in `APIResponse` which becomes `Response`

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way would be to create the appropriate relations between your types.

```
interface Item {
  productId: string
  productName: string
  price: number
}

interface APIItem extends Item {
  factoryId: string,
  status: number,
  category: number,
  priority: number
}

interface Response {
  items: Item[]
}

interface APIResponse extends Response {
  items: APIItem[]
}

// APIResponse is now assignable to Response
let response: Response = ...;
let apiResponse: APIResponse = ...;
response = apiResponse;

// APIItem[] is now also assignable to Item[], but you only loose 
// the type information, the fields will be there actually
const apiItems: APIItem[] = [...];
const items: Item[] = apiItems;
```

So this helps to make the compiler understand how your types are related to each other.

If you want to *"physically"* remove the excess fields, then the best you can do is the `.map` what you posted in your question. You can also use a js library (eg.: [lodash/pluck](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/doc/README.md#_pluckcollection-path)) - but then you defeat the purpose of having statically checked types...